# External monitor starts with Duplicate mode

Tags: 16.04

ubuntu 16.04,
When i start pc, external monitor opens with **duplicate mode** so i always need to switch  to **extended mode** manually..
Is there any method to start external monitor in extended mode by default.

Thanky you

Comment: Does it make any difference if you power on the external monitor first, before turning on the computer?

Comment: No it doesn't make any diff...  what i recently found is that i switched to gnome3 and it now working fine :D